# How does PureComponent work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My understanding was that PureComponent leverages `shouldComponentUpdate()` and does a shallow comparison of state and props but I created a little example that operates differently than I expected.

The example app displays a list of people. Each list item has the ability to change its name. Try it out and inspect the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/81n0omy1q0).

In the parent component, I have a method that looks like this:

```
  updateName(id, newName) {
    const { people } = this.state
    const idx = people.findIndex(person => person.id === id)

    people[idx].name = newName
    this.setState({ people })
  }
```

The object that I'm passing back into `setState` has the same reference as the previous object. In this case, shouldn't this component not update if it's doing a shallow comparison?

Secondly, another part that's unclear, I changed the child component `Person` from PureComponent to Component and I'm still getting the benefit of only the child that was updated re-rendering (I'm doing a console log on each child render if you want to inspect that). Clearly this is something that React is doing internally to decide for the child whether it should update but I assumed that if the component was re-rendering it would re-render everything.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81 .  https://habrahabr.ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/318222/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't this component not update if it's doing a shallow comparison?

Yep. And it isn't updating. You can see that the `App` component's `render()` method does not get called again after the initial render. This means the shallow comparison is working as you expect and the component is (correctly) not updating.

I believe the part that's throwing you off is this line in `Person.prototype.handleSubmit()`:

```
this.setState({ value: '' })
```

Since `oldState.value !== newState.value`, this will trigger a re-render on the modified `Person` component, regardless of whether `Person` is a `PureComponent` or not.

If you take this line out, you will see that nothing updates (the behavior you're expecting).

> Clearly this is something that React is doing internally to decide for the child whether it should update.

Nope, the child is setting its own state. The parent-child relationship is irrelevant here. React will update the child directly.

In the future you should try isolating your tests. The reason this confusion occurred is because you were relying on the `render()` method to determine whether a child received new props. But the `render()` method is called when a child receives new props AND when a child sets new state.

A better test for this situation would have been checking whether `componentWillReceiveProps()` is called, thus eliminating `state` from the picture:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log('receiving props', newProps)
}
```

If you plug this into the `Person` component, you will see that it does not get called. Exactly as you're expecting.

In short, `React.PureComponent` works exactly as you were thinking.

Comment: Excellent and thorough answer @bowheart. One quick clarification, so if I leave in the line `this.setState({ value: '' })` in handleSubmit and added the `componentWillReceiveProps` method as you have it above, the user's name updates when I submit. You're saying the state change tells the render function for the child element to update so it's checking the updated name from props also even though the `componentWillReceiveProps` is not being triggered to let the child know it has updated. Essentially the reference is reflecting the change but not notifying the component.

Comment: @captDaylight Ah. Good catch. You are correct. Even though that object isn't passed again as a new prop, it's still the same object. That referenced object is being mutated. When `render()` reads the `name` property from that object it will be different. This type of implicit state dependency is why the React community is so adamant about keeping data immutable.